# How to scrape using html class name in php crawler?

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I want the rating of this book which is mentioned in the name of class. So, how can I get that class name?

> <p class ="star_rating five"> </p>

```
$prices = $xpath->evaluate('//ol[@class="row"]//li//article//div[@class="product_price"]//p[@class="price_color"]');

$rating =$xpath->evaluate('//ol[@class="row"]//li//article//p[@class]');
```

Comment: Anything not working with the given code?

Comment: I suggest you add more details to your question. What does the variable `$xpath` contain? Is there a snippet of HTML that you are parsing?

Comment: It looks pretty obvious that the given xpath does not work: there's no `ol` tag in the code you've shared, there's no `li` tag, no `article` tag, no `div`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example and it would work fine.

```
$html = '<div><p class ="star_rating five"> </p><div>';
if (!empty($html)) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
 
    $desiredTag = "p";
 
    foreach ($xpath->query('//'.$desiredTag) as $node) {
        $p = $node->getAttribute('class');
        echo $p;
    }
}
```

You can filter out the tags you want specifically & reach to the

node which contains your desired attribute, using `getAttribute` you can get the value provided in it.

try above provided snippet: https://ideone.com/aG8DcN

Comment: actually its not working ... i dont need attribute of classname i just want name of class name  as a result..

Comment: The name of class 'star_rating five' right ?

Comment: @VupeshAwasthi Have you tried the snippet link & checked the output ?

Comment: just one more query how this code work on class inside another class.. for example '<ol class=row ><div><p class ="star_rating five"> </p></div></ol> ';....please help me

Comment: check this it works fine with your specific case as well: https://ideone.com/wfR6n9

Comment: You better post issue / error / exception you're getting or provide your whole case I suspect you're making some other mistakes because the above snippet will work in any case it's querying the whole DOM and not just simple one div.

Comment: this is working fine...i need a solution which have two class..class inside another class..

Comment: give us an example ? You need to understand the code. Once you have loaded the DOM into an object you can query anything even if it's nested and depth level is too deep.

Comment: its not working in class inside class.(nested) ...for example go to  this https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/science_22/index.html... crawl the rating of each book...

Comment: At this point can't help you unless you share your code or more details to the original question.

Comment: its not working in class inside class.(nested) ...for example go to  this https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/science_22/index.html... crawl the rating of each book...

Comment: yes you need to get the <ol> first then loop the <li> and then go to the article and so on, that's how you will get the start rating classes.